# Can someone give me the translation of this Mantra?

Tags: mantras, translation-request, life

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b7SXLECcCA

> Om Lakshmi Vigan Shri Kamala Dharigan Svaha

Thank you.

*By the way, the "Om" of the first 5 seconds is magnificent!*

Comment: Is that a Hindu Mantra?